# Correct grammar...article "a"

Tags: grammar, exclamatives

Somebody can explain me the difference between these two sentences:

**"What a wonderful day?"**

and

**"What wonderful day?"**

Actually I'm not sure if those ones are written in a correct way, I think the article "a", it's not neccesary.

Comment: **What a wonderful day!** is a common expression. **What wonderful day** is an unlikely construction although it might work in the plural: **What wonderful days will dawn when winter turns to spring!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What a wonderful day!

This sentence is an exclamation expressing the speaker's opinion that today is especially wonderful. There are exclamations like this that can be formed with other words, like how and such, too:

http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/howwhat.html

Without the indefinite article, it's a question you might hear in a conversation like the following:

> Do you remember that wonderful day we had last summer?
> What wonderful day?

Answer (score 2):

What a wonderful day?

What wonderful day?

Both the phrases are incorrect.  When you want to say an exclamative phrase or clause, you put a sign of exclamation (!), not a sign of interrogattion (?).  Second, as the word day is a countable noun, you must put the indefinite article "a" in front of "day".  So the correct phrase should be written as follows:

What a wonderful day!